# Is it haram to fake my age online?

Tags: money, work, lying, age

I'm 15 years old (about to be 16 in a month) and I want to make money online as I don't have time for an actual job during the school year. The problem is websites always want workers at least 18 years old. Is it haram to fake my age to be able to work online? If I do fake my age will the money earned not be halal?

The work I intend to do online is simply transcribing audio, adding captions to videos, taking part in surveys and simple freelance work.

Anyways thank you to anybody who replies.

Answer (score 0):

lying is haram, you can use freelancing sites that doesn't require age informations

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, that would be haram if you fill your fake age. It seems you're lying about your age and Islam rejects lying as haram. And the income from that source would also be haram. The better way is to freelance or work with those who accept your limits or who don't get out of your criteria.
Zazakallah